# Full text search not finding pages

Tags: 2013, search

I have a normal page with text and pictures on it. When I search a term or even full sentence from this page, the search will not show up the specific page where it is on. It finds only documents (pdfs) and librarys but not the page where those terms are written down.

Is it not possible to have automatic full text search over pages in Sharepoint 2013?

Useful Information: It is not showing up search results from text in Content Editor Web Parts.

Answer (score 3):

In Central Administration navigate to your Search Service Application (Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Service Applications). In the Search Service Application, navigate to Crawl Log and select “Host Name” in the links at the top. Select the Host name URL where your page exist and paste the URL to your page in the search box below the text “Type a URL or host name. Use the * character as a wildcard”.

Click the search button, and see if your page is crawled correct.

[image]